# How to create or generate the .mlpd file for check the application performance in xamarin profiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello Xamarin team,

I am working on Xamarin forms in Visual Studio 2017 Community, and I wanted to check the app performance in the Xamarin Profiler. For that I need to create an .mlpd to   check the app performance in the Xamarin Profiler. How can I generate this file?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `debug.mono.profile` environment variable to enable the Mono profiler.

> The debug.mono.profile system property enables the profiler. It is equivalent to, and uses the same values as, the mono --profile option. (See the mono(1) man page for more information.)

- https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/#profiler-option-documentation

#### Quick Android Example:

```
adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile "log:calls,alloc,output=/sdcard/Download/output.mlpd,maxframes=8,calldepth=100"

// Exercise your app...

adb pull /sdcard/Download/prof.mlpd ~/Desktop/
adb shell rm /sdcard/Download/prof.mlpd
adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile ""

// View the results:
`which mprof-report` ~/Desktop/prof.mlpd
```

**Note**: `.mlpd` files can become **huge** (not just megabytes, but 10s/100s of gigabytes in size depending upon what options you are using with the "log" profiler, make sure you have the storage available on your device (the Xamarin Profiler streams the log data over TCP and thus does not have this issue)

**!Note!**: If you are trying to store the mlpd file in a location outside of your app's sandbox, Mono will log the error under the `mono-prof` tag. If this is the case, you will need to grant your app write permission (i.e. via Android manifest and runtime permissions) from within the app itself.

```
[mono-prof] Could not create log profiler output file '/sdcard/Download/output.mlpd': Permission denied
```

#### Android Environment:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/environment

#### iOS Environment:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/xs-mono-runtime

#### Xamarin Profiler (Does that all for you and has a nice GUI):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/

Comment: SushiHangover thanks for your reply, ABD shell where do i find can you tell me please . didn't get that in online

Comment: @praveenaHM Android Debug Bridge (`adb`) is a part of the Android SDK :  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Abd application automatically closing while opening

Comment: @praveenaHM ? It is a cmd line utility.

Comment: I got the abd in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools path. its not opening.

Comment: @praveenaHM What do you mean "opening"?, it is a cmd line utility, there is no GUI

Comment: Actually, its not opening  when double click on adb file inside the android skd platform tools.I tried run as administrator alos. Didn't work.

Comment: can you give any example videos  or screenshots about it

Comment: You can get a command prompt by going to `VS for Mac -> Tools -> SDK Command Prompt.` That opens a Terminal window that will allow you to use the ADB utility. Once the Terminal window is open, you can type `adb --help` for example.

Comment: If you want to avoid needing to give extra permissions to read/write external to the app storage sandbox, the default output location is `/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.override/profile.mlpd`.  You can access the app's sandbox by using

(within the adb command line) `adb shell`
(within the general adb shell) `run-as @PACKAGE_NAME@`
(within the app-specific adb shell) `ls files/.__override__`

Comment: How to turn it off? I turned it on and now app runs slower everytimes.

Comment: @AkashKava Clear the `debug.mono.profile` property, i.e. `adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile ""`