# How to use Xamarin Profiler standalone for profile the app

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms in visual studio community 2017. How to profile the xamarin forms app using xamarin profiler.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=vsmac):

> You will need to be a Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber to unlock
>   this feature in either Visual Studio Enterprise on Windows or Visual
>   Studio for Mac on a Mac.

So sadly you can't use the great features of Xamarin Profiler using Visual Studio **Community**, you need Enterprise. You can also get a trial for 30/90 days if I remember, so consider it.

If you want to profile iOS version of your app, I think you should be able to use Instruments tool from XCode, please follow this instructions: [Profiling Xamarin.iOS Applications with Instruments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/using-instruments-to-detect-native-leaks-using-markheap). To open it, go for Tools → Instruments in Visual Studio for Mac.

If you want to profile Android app, check out [Profiling Android Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling), it describes how to do it from Android Studio.

Comment: zolnieruk Thanks for your reply,   Can you see this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=vswin#xamarin-profiler-1. Here they are telling by loading .mlpd file through we can also test our app.

Comment: As a 3rd option, you can manually create the mlpd and use it via Mono's mprof-report or Xamarin's profiler:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234655/how-to-create-or-generate-the-mlpd-file-for-check-the-application-performance-i

Comment: According to [this post from March 2020](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-xamarin-profiler-available-for-professional-s/351884#T-N954439), the Xamarin profiler will be coming to all versions of VS... eventually.